# How to get a signed 32 bit integer from hex bytes without being 2's complement applied to it in java

Tags: java, type-conversion, signed

I have 4bytes of hex values directly without two's complement being applied to signed inetger. How do I get an int value from hex bytes using java.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this work?

```
int value = ((0xff & b4) < 24) | ((0xff & b3) < 16) | ((0xff & b2) < 8) | (0xff & b1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Long. You can't use an int as it's always signed and 4 bytes just won't fit.

```
    Long l = Long.parseLong("FFFFFFFF", 16);
```

Comment: For a signed in, you can use `int l = (int) Long.parseLong("FFFFFFFF", 16);`